# Detecting if two images collide in objective-C and print message

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-animation, collision-detection

I am currently creating a very basic game for iOS. Basically, I have squares animating across the screen, and a "ship" that is controlled using the accelerometer.  I want to detect when the ship hits the squares that are moving, and for some reason my code is not working.

In this block I am creating the animation of a square:

```
    square4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(frameWidth/10, frameHeight/1.35, frameWidth*.1, frameWidth*.1)];
    square4.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"square.png"];
    [self.view addSubview: square4];
    CGPoint origin4 = square4.center;
    CGPoint target4 = CGPointMake(square4.center.x+300, square3.center.y);
    CABasicAnimation *bounce4 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.x"];
    bounce4.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:origin4.x];
    bounce4.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:target4.x];
    bounce4.duration = 2.3;
    bounce4.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    bounce4.autoreverses = YES;
    [square4.layer addAnimation:bounce4 forKey:@"position"];
```

Then I create my ship, and set up the accelerometer, etc.  The problem I am having is that when I run this method, and the ship and square collide, nothing happens! Here's my collision method code:

```
- (void)collisionWithSquares {

CALayer *squareLayer1 = [square.layer presentationLayer];
CALayer *squareLayer2 = [square2.layer presentationLayer];
CALayer *squareLayer3 = [square3.layer presentationLayer];
CALayer *squareLayer4 = [square4.layer presentationLayer];

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ship.frame, squareLayer1.frame)
    || CGRectIntersectsRect(ship.frame, squareLayer2.frame)
    || CGRectIntersectsRect(ship.frame, squareLayer3.frame)
    || CGRectIntersectsRect(ship.frame, squareLayer4.frame) ) {

    //self.currentPoint  = CGPointMake(0, 144);

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!"
                                                    message:@"Mission Failed!"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}  
}
```

I am calling [self collisionWithSquares] here in my init method:

```
self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    self.motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = .05;
    //accelerometer queues up the data
    //handler calls outputaccelera
    [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData  *accelerometerData, NSError *error)
     {
         [self outputAccelerationData:accelerometerData.acceleration];
     }];


    [self.view addSubview: ship];
    [self collisionWithSquares];

}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(imageView1.frame, imageView2.frame)) {
// Do whatever it is you need to do.
}
```

Comment: Even if you answer is this succinct, you should give an extra effort to explain or reinforce why

Answer (score 1):

use the "square.frame", "square2.frame", etc. rather then creating a CALayer for the collision detection. also, test your if statement with only one condition and see if it fires.

Comment: hmm. I tried doing all of that and still no luck.  I also tried to make the ship image just  static image on the display and testing to see if it was just an error in my accelerometer code, but no luck with that either.

Comment: if you're calling [self collisionWithSquares] only in your init method then that's your problem. that will only get called once. you need some sort of a "run loop" to continually check if a collision happened. you may want to setup a NSTimer to continually fire that method, or call it when the accelerometer changes.

Comment: I also can call it in my outputAccelerationData method couldn't I? That way it doesn't get called only once. I tried calling it in there also and still nothing.

Comment: i would start by adding some break points or NSLog messages to see if that method is even being called, then focus on your logic. you may be overlooking a simpler problem.